# removing a child throwing error

Tags: actionscript-3

When I want to remove Child I get error The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller. I tried lots of different methods I found here on stackoverflow, but none worked.

```
if(player.hitTestObject(activePowerup as DisplayObject)
{
    activePowerup.onPlayerPick(player);
    this.parent.removeChild(activePowerup as DisplayObject);
    activePowerups.splice(activePowerup, 1);
}
```

I don't know what the problemis, but I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: I think you can just remove the `as DisplayObject` on line 4.

Comment: What does `trace(parent.getChildIndex(activePowerup))` print? And yes, you don't need to use ` as DisplayObject` in your example if activePowerup inherits from DisplayObject

Answer (score 1):

If your `activePowerup` is definitely a child of `this.parent`, then I suspect the problem is your splice. Assuming `activePowerups` is an `Array`, `splice()` doesn't work as you're expecting ([see the docs here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29)). You need to give `splice()` the *index* of `activePowerup`:

```
activePowerups.splice(activePowerups.indexOf(activePowerup), 1);
```

Otherwise, you're probably splicing out the wrong powerup and then trying to remove the same child twice the next time this code runs.